# Powers of maximal ideal in Dedekind ring

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

Suppose $K$ is a number field (you may suppose $K$ is imaginary quadratic if necessary, but I doubt that matters) with ring of integers $A$, and suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime of $A$. Choose $t, u\in \mathfrak{p}^{n-1}\backslash \mathfrak{p}^n$. Is it always the case that you can find $\alpha\in A$ such that $\alpha u - t\in\mathfrak{p}^n$?

Certainly any such $\alpha$ must not lie in $\mathfrak{p}$, so that $\mathfrak{p} + (\alpha) = A$ and then $\mathfrak{p}^n + \alpha \mathfrak{p}^{n-1} = \mathfrak{p}^{n-1}$; this at least makes it plausible, but I can't find either a construction or a proof. Experimentation with a few small rings shows it to be the case.

(This is part of a larger problem which I can post if necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes $\bar t$ and $\bar u$ are non-zero in the quotient $\mathfrak{p}^{n-1}/\mathfrak{p}^n$.

But $\mathfrak{p}^{n-1}/\mathfrak{p}^n$ is an $A/\mathfrak{p}$-vector space of dimension $1$, thus there exists $\bar a\in A/\mathfrak{p}$ such that
$$
\bar t=\bar a\cdot\bar u
$$
(in fact $\bar a\neq0$).

Lifting to $A$, i.e, choosing a representant $a\in A$ the displayed formula reads
$$
t-au\in\mathfrak{p}^n.
$$

Comment: @reuns Any non trivial subspace in the quotient would lift to an ideal $I$ of $A$ with $\mathfrak{p}^n\subset I\subset\mathfrak{p}^{n-1}$ properly. But there cannot be such ideals in a Dedekind domain (what would be its decomposition as a product of primes?)

Comment: Why is it of dimension $1$ ? With the non-integrally closed $A= \mathbb{Z}[2i], \mathfrak{p}=(2,2i)$ won't $(2,2i)/(2,2i)^2 =(2,2i)/(4,4i)= \{ 2a+2ic\} /\{ 4a+4ic\} = \{0,2,2i,2+2i\}$ while $A/(2,2i) = \mathbb{Z}/(2)$

Comment: @reuns $\Bbb Z[2i]$ is not Dedekind because it's not integrally closed.

Comment: Sure my point is showing where we need that $A$ is a Dedekind domain. So in your argument you are using that $\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{q} = (p)$ for some ideal (if $p$ isn't ramified we don't need that $A$ is a Dedekind domain)

Comment: @reuns No, I'm using the fact that in a Dedekind domain every ideal is a product of prime ideals in a unique way.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a similar argument starting "Localize $A$ at $\mathfrak{p}$"?

Comment: @rogerl, that would make it even simpler once you know that localizations of Dedekind domains at maximal ideals are DVRs. But it's not really necessary to pass through localizations.

Comment: Sorry, my algebra is a tad rusty. If you pass to the localization, then you have $\alpha t^{n-1}$ and $\beta t^{n-1}$ and want to find [a unit] $\mu$ such that $\alpha-\mu\beta\in (t)$. This is easy to do; can one then lift it back via Hensel's Lemma?